# Kinetic scrolling in Linux and Synaptics

Tags: linux, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

Is there a way to enable kinetic scrolling in Synaptic drivers on Linux?

I don't mind compiling "weird" drivers or kernel modules.

Answer (score 3):

Is this helpful? http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1009310.html

Comment: Kinetic pointer movement != scrolling.

Comment: Um.  I didn't say it was.  I referenced the link because the OP in the discussion apparently patched the Synaptic driver to have some semblance of kinetic scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

In Syanptics terms it's 'Coasting' rather than kinetic scroll.

```
synclient CoastingSpeed=0
```

will fix the issue. Well, you could also add it to your `xorg.conf`.